# JavaScript: when string added to DocumentFragment.innerHTML, there are no children, how to fix?

Tags: javascript, documentfragment

When some html string added to DocumentFragment `innerHTML` property, there are no children exists. But same action with Element created by `createElement` show children. I created simple example for comparing innerHTML behavior for DocumentFragment and simple Element:

```
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const div = document.createElement('div')

fragment.innerHTML = "<i>Test</i>";
console.log('fragment children:', fragment.children); // empty
fragment.innerHTML = "<i><b>Test</b></i>";
console.log('fragment children:', fragment.children); // empty

div.innerHTML = "<i>Test</i>";
console.log('div children:', div.children) // has children
div.innerHTML = "<i><b>Test</b></i>";
console.log('div children:', div.children)  // has children
```

But fragment can show children added by appendChild:

```
const span = document.createElement('span');
const fragment2 = document.createDocumentFragment();
fragment2.appendChild(span);
console.log('fragment children for appendChild', fragment2.children);
```

How to fix this weird DocumentFragment behavior ?

**ADDITIONAL**: I need DocumentFragment as temporary HTML container.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b0yndwk5/) with reproducing the problem.

Comment: To downvoters: what's wrong with my question ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div` inherits from the `HTMLElement` prototype, a child of the `Node` prototype

`DocumentFragment` inherits directly from the `Node` prototype.

This is to say that `div` has all of the Node methods and properties as well as all HTMLElement methods and properties.

`DocumentFragment` only has Node methods and properties.

Though the Node prototype has the ability to have children, `innerHTML` does not exist as an innate property. This is only available on `HTMLElement` and its children (in this case `HTMLDivElement` ).

Assigning to `innerHTML` on a child of a `Node` prototype simply creates the property `innerHTML` with your string as a value, but does nothing more.

Basically, elements have internal wiring that tells them what to `do` when `innerHTML` is assigned/updated. Nodes do not.

You can see this below:

```js
const fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
const div = document.createElement('div');

console.log("innerHTML in fragment: " + ('innerHTML' in fragment) );
console.log("innerHTML in element: " + ('innerHTML' in div) );
```

---

In order to use something as a `container` and utilize `innerHTML` you would really just need to create an element that contains what you're trying to add. You can use a number of different things like a `template` Element or `DOMParser`, but honestly the easiest is just to create a separate `div` and classify it as a `container`

```js
let container = document.createElement("div");
container.className = "container";

let div = document.createElement("div");
container.className = "child";

container.appendChild(div);

document.body.appendChild(container);
```

```css
.container {

width: 100px;
height: 100px;
border: 1px solid red;
}

.child {
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 border: 1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the explanation. But this is not an answer. The question was: how to fix. So, it seems only way to fix this is to use `createElement` to create temporary dom ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo You're welcome. I can give you an alternative, sure, but what exactly are you "fixing" ? You simply need a container that allows for `innerHTML` ? I would think a `div` or a `section` would suffice.

Comment: additional: I need temporary container that allowable to apply querySelector on it

Comment: great! Btw, when some operations performs on this container does it affects the DOM ?

Comment: @SergioIvanuzzo When you append to the DOM, a clone of what you're appending is what's added. `appendChild` returns the added DOM nodes though. So in order to get a reference if you need to edit the DOM node, you can simply do something like `let editable = document.body.appendChild(container); editable.id = "newid";`

Comment: Glad I could help. If you have further questions please post them in new threads, thanks!